Django REST Framework: TypeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable for nested M2M serializer
I have two models: Recipe and Ingredient which are connected by ManyToMany through RecipeIngredient:
class Recipe(models.Model):
    ...
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Ingredient',
        through='RecipeIngredient',
    )
    ...

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=LENGTH_FOR_CHARFIELD
    )
    measurement_unit = models.CharField(
        max_length=LENGTH_FOR_CHARFIELD
    )

class RecipeIngredient(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()

I also have a serializer class for Recipe with nested serializer for RecipeIngredient:
class IngredientRecipeSerializerForWrite(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = RecipeIngredient
        fields = ('ingredient_id', 'amount')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        recipe_ingredient = RecipeIngredient.objects.create(**self.initial_data)
        return recipe_ingredient


class RecipeSerializerForWrite(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ingredients = IngredientRecipeSerializerForWrite(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = (
            ...
            'ingredients',
            ...
        )

    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs['ingredients'] = self.initial_data['ingredients']
        for item in attrs['ingredients']:
            item['ingredient_id'] = item.pop('id')
        return attrs

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tags = validated_data.pop('tags')
        ingredients = validated_data.pop('ingredients')
        recipe = Recipe.objects.create(**validated_data)
        recipe.tags.set(tags)
        for item in ingredients:
            item['recipe'] = recipe
            ingredients_serializer = IngredientRecipeSerializerForWrite(
                data=item
            )
            ingredients_serializer.is_valid()
            ingredients_serializer.save()
        return recipe

Data from request must come in a format:
  "ingredients": [
    {
      "id": {{firstIndredientId}},
      "amount": {{firstIngredientAmount}}
    },
    {
      "id": {{secondIndredientId}},
      "amount": {{secondIngredientAmount}}
    }

I'm trying to pass the data to IngredientRecipeSerializerForWrite and create objects there, but i'm getting error
TypeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable

I'm using serializer for RecipeIngredient model because i need to pass amount value to that relation
Before i handled it with serializers.ListField and created m2m object directly in RecipeSerializerForWrite, but now i need to change it for nested serialization and don't know how to do it properly

You probably already solved it, but if no - can you post the entire traceback here?
